# Files are getting dropped while reading in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In our project, we are using Informatica PowerCenter to process the files and to load the data into the database. Sometimes, we get an issue of some files getting dropped while loading. We have checked ftps logs of file copying to Informatica server, we can see the files present in server however when we are checking the data, some of the files are getting dropped randomly.
The funny thing is, that when we reload the data again, it gets loaded fine.
The above issue seems to be occurring frequently within 2-3 every months. We need some help in understanding if we are missing out on something while checking the data.

Comment: i think the ftp process is not getting complete and so partial result. so you need to ask them to sent a completion file once FTP completes and then create infa a file watch.

Comment: I have checked the ftp logs, it seems the file is copied to infa server correctly.

Comment: is it possible one file overwriting another?

Comment: post reloading it is working fine and in the logs we see entry of all the files every time. Does not look like to be the case of overwriting.

Comment: Can anyone help with the same?

Comment: difficult to tell at which point its ignoring the files. If infa sees the file it must pick them up. You can enable session to keep old infa log files. Pls carefully check them when its dropping and see if you can find any pattern.

Comment: From our end, we have checked more or less everything but we do not see a pattern here.

Comment: is it possible Ftp is halfway through and informatica is picking up correct rows. You can also put an audit to capture how many records its processing and pinpoint failure point.